# How to Post a Json body from a java/jackson Object in Gatling 2

Tags: json, scala, jackson, gatling

I'm building an object like this:

```
val car = new Car()
car.setName("BMW")
```

Please notice that the object Car is a jackson Object

The goal is to do a post with the car json as a body

```
val httpConf = http.baseURL("http://localhost:8080/v1")
    .acceptHeader("*/*")
    .connection("keep-alive")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")

val carRequest = scenario("Create a car")
    .exec(
        http("create a car").post("/cars/").body(car).asJSON
)
```

But this doesn't works. It expect Body object in body()

How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`body(car.asJson)` instead of `body(car).asJSON`

Comment: it get this: "value asJson is not a member of org.Car" is there an import that must be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this out:

```
.body(StringBody(car))
.asJSON
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

`.body(StringBody(car)).asJSON`

Comment: Explain your code, it's not enough to put a possible solution